# Find the count of the characters in a string considering escaped characters as single character

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-apps-script, escaping

JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape character. Using apps script I want to count the number of characters for example

```
abc\n\n\n\\\\
```

should return 8

I tried, but the output is incorrect

```
var x = str.replace("\\\\","\\").split("\\");
var len=0;

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
   if(x[i]) len = len + x[i].length; //else len+=1;
}
showAlert(len);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `String#length`?

```js
var a = 'abc\n\n\n\\\\';

console.log(a.length);
```

Comment: ha ha 23s too fast for me :p

Answer (score 0):

When i do

```
let s = "abc\n\n\n\\\\";
console.log(s.length);
```

it gives me 8, isn't it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you do \\ you actually push js to treat second backslash as a character